# QUESTA + Modelsim using using command Gate Level Simulation

Tags: delay, fpga, modelsim, quartus, wave

I have installed Quartus V20 + ModelSim V20. It's the first time I use that. I have buyed a book to try to understand how to simulate / use a FPGA system.
I have done a simple cirtuit to check the delay and glich of the gate.
Circuits characteristic (sample taken from the Book - 2 in and 4 out):

```
//Y0 = !A and !B
//Y1 = !A and B
//Y2 = A and !B
//Y3 = A and B

module decoder( A0, A1, Y0, Y1, Y2, Y3 );
input wire  A0;
input wire  A1;
output wire Y0;
output wire Y1;
output wire Y2;
output wire Y3;

wire    SYNTHESIZED_WIRE_4;
wire    SYNTHESIZED_WIRE_5;

assign  Y0 = SYNTHESIZED_WIRE_4 & SYNTHESIZED_WIRE_5;
assign  Y1 = SYNTHESIZED_WIRE_4 & A1;
assign  Y2 = A0 & SYNTHESIZED_WIRE_5;
assign  Y3 = A1 & A0;
assign  SYNTHESIZED_WIRE_4 =  \~A0;
assign  SYNTHESIZED_WIRE_5 =  \~A1;
endmodule
```

In theory I shall have some delay (about 7ns) and a glich on Y3 when I change from 01 to 10.
This assumption derive from the book and I want to check with my eyes :-)

Test Code:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module decoder_tb();
reg \[1:0\] A;
wire \[3:0\] Y;

decoder UUT (.A0(A\[0\]),.A1(A\[1\]),.Y0(Y\[0\]),.Y1(Y\[1\]),.Y2(Y\[2\]),.Y3(Y\[3\]));

initial
begin
A=2'b00; #1000;
A=2'b01; #1000;
A=2'b10; #1000;
A=2'b11; #1000; $stop;
end
endmodule
```

Settings (find on the web):

- Assignments->Settings->EDA Tools Settings->Simulation->

  - Test Benches... -> Design Instance = UUT
  - More EDA Netlist Writer Settings ... -> ALL off

Device:
Assignments->Device-> Cyclone V 5CEFA4F23C7

But when I start the simulation: Tools->Run Simulation Tools->Gate Level Simulation
the wave hane not the delay. In some viedo a windows appear when I click on Gate ..., but in my case, is not shown.

Another question: in the book it's write to check the delay BEFORE the Gate command in:
Compile Design->Timing Analysis->View Report-> [TimeQuest Timing Analysis->Datasheet Report|Propagation Delay]
I don't have the section in the []...

I have see some of video and read some page on the web, but I don't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved.
In another Forum (Intel), I have found that:

*"Referring to the user guide, https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/documentation/gtt1529956823942.html (Simulation Levels), gate level timing simulation is not supported for Cyclone V. It is supported only for the Arria® II GX/GZ, Cyclone® IV, MAX® II, MAX® V, and Stratix® IV device families."*

Thanks to all.